# Puppeteer How to call the 2nd div from the same class

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Let  us just say on a website there are two divs with the same class/id. How I am able to call the 2nd class with the same name/id?

```
await page.type('.sameclass', "DifferentSpot1")
await page.type('.sameclass', "DifferentSpot2")
```

In javascript the query selector would be like this.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.sameclass')[0]
document.querySelectorAll('.sameclass')[1]
```

This is what it looks like in the query selector.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.sameclass:nth-child(1)')[0]
document.querySelectorAll('.sameclass:nth-child(1)')[1]
```

Comment: See the below answer, you should use $eval to get the array of names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

Get the array of selector names through $eval and the use them for to find the elements where you'll execute type

```
const classValues = await page.$eval('body', body => {
    return Array.from(body.querySelectorAll('.sameclass'))  
 });

await page.type(classValues[0], "DifferentSpot1")
await page.type(classValues[1], "DifferentSpot2")
```

Comment: i get this error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: It should not retrun undefined if you are using correct selector. Check your slectors on line 1 and 2 of this answer

Comment: Yeah I checked the selectors and all of them are correct.

Comment: document.body.querySelectorAll('.sameclass') do you get you classes when you run this in your console?